# efficient way to insert following integers to a vector

Tags: actionscript-3, vector

Is there a more efficient way to do :

```
var firstItemIndex:int = 220;
var lastItemIndex:int = 880;
var indices:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>();

for(var i:int = firstItemIndex; i <= lastItemIndex; i++) {
    indices.push(i);
}
```

Short explanation  -  is there a more efficient way to insert integers from `StartNumber` to `EndNumber` without having to loop ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completey sure how AS3 handles memory allocation under the hood, but it may be more efficient to make a fixed length vector instead of a variable one:

```
var firstItemIndex:int = 220;
var lastItemIndex:int = 880;
var indices:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(lastItemIndex - firstItemIndex + 1, true);

function setItem(item:int, index:int, vector:Vector.<int>):void{
    vector[index] = firstItemIndex + index;
}
indices.forEach(setItem);
```